# Android Fragment view does not scroll when keyboard is up

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard

I am loading a fragment like this

```
String tag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment,tag);
transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
transaction.commit();
```

The activity has this property set

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

In my view I have a button at the bottom that I want to keep on top of the keyboard. This is what my fragment layout file looks like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

         <LinearLayout..../>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/activate_button"
  style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I have an EiditText in this view and when I request focus the soft keyboard appears but view doesn't scroll.

Can anyone tell me why view is not resizing when keyboard is up?

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions that worked for me

Put this in the onCreate of your fragment:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Or

Use a ScrollView as parent of your FrameLayout in the Activity, like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <FrameLayout/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Change  Parent **RelativeLayout** `

**android:layout_height="wrap_content"** 
 into
     **android:layout_height="match_parent"**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activate_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry for not posting it correctly. I am using android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". I just update my post. Thanks!

Comment: still button not appear on top of the keyboard

Comment: No, the view is not resizing so the button remains at the bottom of screen behind the keyboard. It may have to with that I am using android.R.id.content to replace the fragment but I have to use it because I want my fragment to be full screen.

Comment: Tried making RelativeLayout height "match_parent" did not work if that is what you are suggesting.